# Удаление пробелов в строке

Tags: c#, строки

Есть строка которую я хочу перевести в число(например `String myString ="2 014"`),но так как она имеет пробел выдаёт Exception. как можно в строке удалить пробел?

Comment: какое число должно быть? целое или дробное?

Comment: @Grundy целое число.

Comment: и пробел это только разделитель тысяч? или может стоять в любом месте строки?

Comment: @Grundy может быть 20 231. Я считываю с сайта кол-во человек. и сотые всегда отделяются тысячными.

Comment: в метод parse можно передать параметр разрешающий разделители

Comment: @Grundy хотя по сути число всегда будет меньше 10 000. Поэтому да, пробел всегда в одном месте.

Comment: myString.Replace(" ", "") не?

Comment: int n = Convert.ToInt32(myString.Replace(" ", string.Empty);

Comment: "сотые всегда отделяются тысячными" ???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Метод `int.Parse` имеет несколько перегрузок, принимающих стиль чисел и провайдер формата.

Итак, имеем строку с разделителем груп (тысяч):

```
String myString = "2 014";
```

---

В первую очередь, нужно указать стиль, разрешающий сепаратор групп:

```
int n = int.Parse(myString, NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
```

Это будет работать, если в текущей культуре используется именно пробел в качестве разделителя групп. Узнать его можно, например, так:

```
var ci = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
Console.WriteLine(ci.Name);
Console.WriteLine("'" + ci.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator + "'");
```

В русской культуре, с именем `ru-RU` это пробел по умолчанию. Но если приложение запущено на компьютере с другой культурой, то разделитель может быть другим. Скажем, в англоязычной `en-US` это будет запятая: `,`.

---

Поэтому лучше не полагаться на культуру по умолчанию, а задать нужный провайдер формата.

```
int n = int.Parse(myString, NumberStyles.AllowThousands, new CultureInfo("ru-RU"));
```

в данном случае используется явное создание культуры `ru-RU`.

---

Так как для разбора числа нужна лишь небольшая часть параметров культуры, то можно создать просто провайдер формата чисел:

```
NumberFormatInfo nfi = new NumberFormatInfo();
nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";
int n = int.Parse(myString, NumberStyles.AllowThousands, nfi);
```

Тут явно задаётся пробел в качестве разделителя групп. Культура как таковая не используется.

---

---

Напоследок обращу внимание, что значения перечисления `NumberStyles` можно комбинировать. Если, скажем, пробелы могут быть ещё и в начале и в конце разбираемой строки, то добавим:

```
var nfi = new NumberFormatInfo();
nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";
var styles = NumberStyles.AllowThousands | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite | NumberStyles.AllowTrailingWhite;
int n = int.Parse(myString, styles, nfi);
```

Таким образом, можно очень гибко настраивать разбор строк.

Answer (score 6):

В метод [Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/9yaffedz(v=vs.110).aspx) можно передать флаг ([NumberStyles.AllowThousands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.globalization.numberstyles(v=vs.110).aspx)) указывающий, что в переданной строке для разделения групп используется специальный символ, зависящей от установленной культуры.

Если текущая культура `ru-RU`, то *NumberGroupSeparator* равен пробелу, поэтому код может выглядеть так:

```
var num = int.Parse("2 134", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
```

Чтобы сделать более независимое решение, третьим параметром в `Parse` можно передать [`NumberFormatInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo(v=vs.110).aspx), в котором установить нужный разделитель, например так:

```
var num = int.Parse("2 134", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands, new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo() { NumberGroupSeparator = " " });
```

---

Что интересно, при выставлении данного флага, даже несмотря на значение свойства *NumberGroupSizes* задающего три цифры в группе, значение, в котором пробелами будет разделена каждая цифра - также будет корректно разобрано:

```
int.Parse("2 1 3 4", NumberStyles.AllowThousands, new NumberFormatInfo() { NumberGroupSeparator = " ",  }) == 2134
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно вот так:

```
String myString = "2 01 4";
int count = int.Parse(myString.Replace(" ", string.Empty));
```

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так

```
string sNumber = "23 45 5558";
string number=null;
foreach (var item in sNumber.Split(' '))
 {
   number += item;
 }
int convertNumber = int.Parse(number);
```

Comment: А зачем собирать вручную??? Если гулять то уже по-полной: `string.Join("", sNumber .Split());`

Comment: @nick_n_a сразу написал, не думал но спасибо так ;)

Answer (score 2):

Можно так:

```
int count = Convert.ToInt32(myString.Replace(" ", ""));
```