# Как изменить десятичный разделитель в C#

Tags: c#, строки, float

Например, у меня есть `string value = "1;1"`

И я хочу, чтобы все прошло успешно `float.TryParse(value, out float number);`

Соотвественно, number должен быть  равен `number = 1,1`

Comment: Ну, можно заменить в строке все возможные варианты разделителя на точку предварительно

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/672418/184217 - делайте по аналогии

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Мне кажется, правильный метод — получить `CultureInfo`, которая будет считать `;` десятичным разделителем. Если такой `CultureInfo` нет, её легко создать самому на основе любой существующей, предварительно склонировав её: вот такой код

```cs
string value = "1;1";
var ci = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();
ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ";";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci; // не CurrentUICulture!
Console.WriteLine(float.TryParse(value, out _));
```

выводит `True`.

---

Решение с переустановкой `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` несёт *глобальный* эффект: у всех строк в данной программе (ну хорошо, в данном потоке) в качестве десятичного разделителя будет использована точка с запятой. Это скорее всего будет иметь негативный эффект, если у вас в программе (явно или неявно) происходит конвертация чисел из «нормального» строкового представления. Например, для WPF-приложений решение с глобальной переустановкой вряд ли подойдёт.

В таком случае, вам необходима лишь локальная переустановка: вместо последних двух строк примера просто

```cs
Console.WriteLine(float.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Float, ci, out _));
```

---

Возможно, вам нужно установить какую-то конкретную `CultureInfo` на основе ваших бизнес-требований. Конкретно `CultureInfo` с символом `;` в качестве разделителя я на своей системе не обнаружил (кроме точки и запятой, используется [символ `٫`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/066b/index.htm) языками, родственными арабскому), но возможно у вас `;` был лишь для примера.

Comment: Думаю, стоит добавить в ответ упоминание о перегрузке, которая непосредственно принимает IFormatProvider, а то чует мое сердце, что ТС такое поведение нужно в одном конкретном месте, а он ради этого сменит культуру для всего текущего потока, что есть моветон :)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov: Кстати да, но это уже завтра утром :)

Comment: Это правильно. Доброй ночи)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov: Сделано! // Доброе утро)

Comment: Знаю, знаю, но upvote и так со вчера стоит хД